# AngularJs - How to get cell data of clicked row

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, ng-grid, angular-grid

I have created an Angular Js ui-grid, and last column consist with a button.
when click on that button i need to get the data of each cell of that row.
if anyone can help me to figure this out would be appreciate.

```
var removeTemplate = '<input type="button" value=""  style="background: url(../../Content/images/del-currency.png);widht:60px;height:30px"  ng-click="removeRow()" />';
    $scope.selectedCurrencyGrid = {
                    data: 'selectedCurrencies',
                    multiSelect: false,
                    selectedItems: $scope.selectedCurrencyRow,
                    enableColumnResize: false,
                    enableRowSelection: true,
                    columnDefs: [
                          { field: 'Name', displayName: 'Name' },
                          {
                              field: 'IsDefault',
                              displayName: 'Default',
                              cellTemplate: '<input type="radio" name="radAnswer" ng-model="row.entity.IsDefault">'
                          },
                          { name: 'Photo', field: 'photoP', displayName: '', cellTemplate: removeTemplate }
                    ]

                };


$scope.removeRow = function () {
            var index = this.row.rowIndex;
            //need to get cell data of selected row
        };
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `row.entity` to your template function,
this will give you access to the object properties (row cells):

`<input type="button" value=""  style="background: url(../../Content/images/del currency.png);widht:60px;height:30px" ng-click="removeRow(row.entity)" />';`

Make sure your function in the conteroller gets a parameter:

```
$scope.removeRow = function (selectedRowObject) {
            //Your logic...
        };
```

Comment: No problem, I recommend looking at their documentation, they have a lot of great features. http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api